# Get UITextView data in custom cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell with a **`UITextView`** in it and `outlet` for that **`UITextView`** is in the customCell file.

Now in my **`viewController`** I have **`tableView`** and I create and add that custom cell into my table.
After this I can't access **`UITextView`** and get its data as its `outlet` in the customCell file. I can't move the outlet to my **`viewController`** as I need it there.
How can I do this **(access the `UITextView` in my `viewController`)**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set that delegate of cell's `textView` with your `viewController`, First set its delegate inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomTableCell 
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row //In case you have multiple textView
    return cell
}
```

Now you can get this textView inside its `UITextViewDelegate` method.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    print(textView.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a local variable in your `viewController` to get the data of your `UITextView`. Then implement the `tableView`s `delegate` method

```
 //this is your local variable declared in viewCOntroller
 var myTextViewText: String?

//And this is your delegate method
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCell
    myTextViewText = cell.textView.text //here you will get the text of your cell's textView
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to get user input when a button is tapped. This here won't do that as the user might not select the row after the input is changed.